# Mongo query to find top value for some unique keys

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have some documents in a collection like

```
{ "age" : 22, "value" : 234 },
{ "age" : 23, "value" : 54 },
{ "age" : 22, "value" : 260 },
{ "age" : 22, "value" : 23 }
```

Here we have different age and values. I need to pick the highest value for each age. so the result should be like.

```
{ "age" : 23, "value" : 54 }
{ "age" : 22, "value" : 260 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) query should do the trick:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: "$age", value: {$max: "$value"}}},
    {$project: {_id: 0, age: "$_id", value: 1}}
])
```

Comment: how can i use this with find() ?

Comment: You cannot, as find can only be used to filter/project documents. The functionality you request is available in aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) your document by "age" and use the [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) accumulator  operator to return the maximum for each group.

```js
db.people.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$age", 
        "value": { "$max": "$value" } 
    }}
])
```

Which produces:

```js
{ "_id" : 23, "value" : 54 }
{ "_id" : 22, "value" : 260 }
```

Note that you will need to add another [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage to the pipeline in other to get your exact output but this will cause a drop of performance.

Comment: how can i use this with find() ?

Comment: @RahulTailwal you simply can't. This is not a job for `.find()`